# How to copy and paste data from SAP to an excel file already saved with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

When I have completed a transaction, I have my data locally displayed in SAP. I would like to copy and paste all my displayed data and then paste them in the right place using VBA. 
I would also like to know if there is a solution so that when the message "No data has been selected" is displayed, my program continues to run anyway.

```
 Sub FOS()

 If Not IsObject(App) Then
 Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
 Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
 End If
 If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
 Set Connection = App.Children(0)
 End If
 If Not IsObject(session) Then
 Set session = Connection.Children(0)
 End If
 If IsObject(WScript) Then
 WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
 WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
 End If
 session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87011964"
 ...
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_GRID").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBERDATUM").Text = "31.12.2019"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBEREICH1").Text = "01"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSRTVR").Text = "Z003"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_GRID").SetFocus
 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[19]").press
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkPA_XGBAF").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkPA_XGBAF").SetFocus
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

 End Sub
```

I would like to copy and paste data from SAP to excel. 
In addition, sometimes my program stops when I get a message such as "No data selected".

Comment: When you say _when the message "No data has been selected" is displayed_ do you mean a popup displays the message and your code errors out, or do you mean the message is displayed on the bottom of the SAP window?

Comment: @Nacorid I would like say :  when the message "No data has been selected" is displayed do you mean a popup displays the message and your code errors out

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the error message? As vague as you describe it, my best guess is that your code is not selecting an item from a list before continuing, which promps your SAP  client to tell you to select data.

Comment: yes the transaction has not found anything, but when I have several transactions to perform I want when SAP does not find any data it switches to another transaction
Excuse me, I hope you understand, the English language is not my mother tongue.